# Android completely stop WebView from scaling

Tags: android, webview, scaling

I have a WebView, and I have the following code:

```
webview.setInitialScale(75);
```

I also have zooming disabled:

```
webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
```

Both of these pieces of code work very well until any sort of textbox (input field) is selected within the WebView, then the application scales to 100%.

I'm trying to figure out how to intercept and stop the scale from taking place when a textbox is selected, however I've had no luck with the following:

[`onCheckIsTextEditor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onCheckIsTextEditor%28%29) - This doesn't seem to fire when the textbox is clicked

I can change the Scale back to 75% after the page scales by Overriding the [`onScaleChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) method within the WebViewClient class.  However this can only be done by looping through with the [`zoomOut()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#zoomOut%28%29) method until the proper scale is met.

To me it seems there must be a location where the click actually fires the event to focus the textbox and redraw the view to scale it (and `onScaleChanged()` is called), I just haven't been able to locate it yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the activity calling "onPause" and "onResume" when the Soft Keyborad appears?
And well, onCheckIsTextEditor is not triggered AFAIA, you can explicity call it if you want to check if a WebView can edit text. And well, your text box is HTML/Javascript, isn't it? So it's not even a view itself.

Comment: Neither onPause or onResume are triggered when the Soft Keyboard appears.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I've got the same problem, and can't seem to find a solution...

Comment: I was never able to solve it -- spent hours on it.  From all of my tests it is being caused by the HTC Touch UI which seems to override android scaling and has no API.

Comment: I managed to fix this, and posted my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829537/disable-zoom-when-clicking-on-form-fields-within-a-webview/7287456#7287456