# Disabling the zoom functionality of webview,when clicked on the textfield?

Tags: android, webview, zooming

I am having a WebView with many text field and some images. I disabled all the zoom and zoom controls in the webview. But my problem is when I click on the text field its getting zoomed. I want to disable the whole zoom of the WebView even I don't want to get zoomed when clicked on the text field. I had gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829537/disable-zoom-when-clicking-on-form-fields-within-a-webview) and tried all these ways but still am having a problem of getting the zoomed when clicked on the text field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the answer

```
webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
```

Comment: Hopefully it will work on most of the devices.It worked for me.

Comment: But what if your app relies on settings other than the above? :(

Comment: It doesn't work on all devices. For example, it doesn't work on Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 running KitKat.