# Disable zoom when clicking in a form in a Webview in Android 4.4

Tags: android, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I have a `WebView` in my app that has a form in the HTML with editable text fields. When the user taps on one of these fields, the `WebView` zooms in slightly, which I don't want. This only happens in Android 4.4 because of how I'm scaling the `WebView` for older versions (see code below).

I've seen [Disable zoom when clicking on form fields within a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829537/disable-zoom-when-clicking-on-form-fields-within-a-webview), which addresses my question for older Android versions, solving the problem using `WebSettings.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR)`, but that setting is deprecated in 4.4. Even still, I've tried a variety of combinations including setting this property, and my `WebView` still gets zoomed in.

Code creating the `WebView`:

```
public View createView(float parentWidth) {

    mWebView = new ObservableWebView(mContext);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    //Listener for Console Messages
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());        

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
        mWebView.setInitialScale(Globals.convertDpToPx(100));
    } else{
        WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
        settings.setSupportZoom(false);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    }

    loadURL();
    return mWebView;
}

public void loadURL() {
    mWebView.clearHistory();
    mWebView.removeAllViews();
    mWebView.loadUrl(mData.getUrl());       
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You could add to the head of your HTML page the tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

And, if you can't change the original HTML, you can alter it running a bit of JavaScript code after the page has been loaded in your `WebViewClient`. Something like:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl("javascript:"
    + "var newMeta = document.createElement('meta');"
    + "newMeta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');"
    + "newMeta.setAttribute('content', 'user-scalable=no, width=device-width');"
    + "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newMeta);"
    );
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
}
```

I've tested it on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 10.1 running KitKat. On other devices this code causes some side effects, so it's better to execute it only if you are on KitKat or higher.

Comment: I've got the same issue on android 5.1, your onPageFinished solution solved the problem. Tks !

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabling zoom by setting a [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

You need to call `settings.setUseWideViewport(true);` for that to take effect.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the HTML. I've tried `settings.setUseWideViewport(true)` to no avail. I've conceded by allowing the user to zoom in 4.4. It's not ideal, but not the end of the world.